# Trailing 12 months calculation not giving expected results

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregate

I have a table of daily data that i'm trying to add trailing twelve months column to with the sum of the revenue by id, product, currency, and date truncated to month.
I put together some random sample data.
The question is, why do neither of the two aggregate function give the right answer?

```
create table test (day date, id int, product varchar, cur varchar, amount int);
insert into test
values
('10/1/2023', 259, 'A', 'USD', 558), ('9/30/2023', 1502, 'C', 'USD', 1991), ('9/29/2023', 1164, 'A', 'CAD', 1476), ('9/24/2023', 1469, 'A', 'CAD', 681), ('9/20/2023', 220, 'B', 'USD', 279), ('9/19/2023', 222, 'B', 'CAD', 1731), ('9/15/2023', 1822, 'B', 'CAD', 85), ('9/12/2023', 1888, 'A', 'USD', 251), ('9/10/2023', 1457, 'A', 'USD', 584), ('9/6/2023', 179, 'A', 'CAD', 1291), ('9/4/2023', 1307, 'C', 'USD', 944), ('9/3/2023', 374, 'B', 'USD', 894), ('8/29/2023', 866, 'B', 'CAD', 349), ('8/28/2023', 1053, 'B', 'CAD', 171), ('8/23/2023', 1493, 'C', 'USD', 1439), ('8/22/2023', 655, 'B', 'USD', 82), ('8/20/2023', 751, 'A', 'USD', 1994), ('8/19/2023', 517, 'B', 'CAD', 1425), ('8/18/2023', 1233, 'B', 'CAD', 570), ('8/16/2023', 77, 'C', 'USD', 384), ('8/12/2023', 315, 'A', 'USD', 1689), ('8/11/2023', 1968, 'A', 'USD', 1816), ('8/11/2023', 121, 'B', 'CAD', 628), ('8/9/2023', 1868, 'B', 'USD', 1940), ('8/8/2023', 1054, 'C', 'USD', 1176), ('8/6/2023', 336, 'C', 'CAD', 1864), ('8/6/2023', 1861, 'C', 'CAD', 908), ('7/31/2023', 1151, 'C', 'USD', 1531), ('7/29/2023', 1385, 'A', 'USD', 1115), ('7/27/2023', 468, 'B', 'CAD', 446), ('7/24/2023', 425, 'B', 'CAD', 1419), ('7/18/2023', 1784, 'B', 'USD', 1688), ('7/18/2023', 595, 'B', 'USD', 980), ('7/18/2023', 374, 'B', 'USD', 838), ('7/18/2023', 1159, 'C', 'USD', 10), ('7/17/2023', 374, 'A', 'USD', 1085), ('7/14/2023', 1838, 'B', 'CAD', 827), ('7/14/2023', 893, 'C', 'USD', 940), ('7/9/2023', 3, 'B', 'CAD', 1831), ('7/9/2023', 1655, 'C', 'CAD', 1802), ('7/6/2023', 787, 'C', 'CAD', 1493), ('7/5/2023', 247, 'A', 'USD', 1756), ('7/5/2023', 1073, 'B', 'CAD', 1660), ('7/4/2023', 1853, 'B', 'USD', 1955), ('7/4/2023', 371, 'A', 'USD', 202), ('7/1/2023', 376, 'A', 'USD', 1191), ('6/30/2023', 1990, 'B', 'CAD', 1234), ('6/28/2023', 1598, 'C', 'CAD', 1665), ('6/26/2023', 938, 'B', 'CAD', 1939), ('6/25/2023', 1940, 'A', 'USD', 678), ('6/22/2023', 1554, 'A', 'CAD', 1459), ('6/22/2023', 1491, 'C', 'CAD', 350), ('6/21/2023', 1215, 'C', 'USD', 1461), ('6/19/2023', 472, 'C', 'CAD', 250), ('6/16/2023', 1626, 'A', 'USD', 1120), ('6/15/2023', 1545, 'C', 'CAD', 1956), ('6/13/2023', 443, 'B', 'USD', 344), ('6/11/2023', 1251, 'B', 'USD', 1290), ('6/11/2023', 412, 'B', 'USD', 1542), ('6/10/2023', 350, 'C', 'USD', 1862), ('6/8/2023', 201, 'C', 'USD', 107), ('6/8/2023', 1171, 'B', 'CAD', 1364), ('6/6/2023', 1725, 'B', 'CAD', 570), ('6/6/2023', 1050, 'C', 'CAD', 947), ('6/6/2023', 1588, 'C', 'CAD', 83), ('6/4/2023', 163, 'C', 'USD', 319), ('6/4/2023', 276, 'A', 'USD', 1159), ('5/30/2023', 1000, 'C', 'CAD', 564), ('5/29/2023', 1700, 'C', 'USD', 1498), ('5/27/2023', 474, 'A', 'USD', 1127), ('5/26/2023', 551, 'A', 'CAD', 1904), ('5/26/2023', 311, 'C', 'USD', 1036), ('5/25/2023', 590, 'B', 'USD', 958), ('5/24/2023', 1562, 'A', 'CAD', 836), ('5/23/2023', 400, 'A', 'USD', 907), ('5/23/2023', 1411, 'B', 'CAD', 1675), ('5/21/2023', 311, 'C', 'CAD', 1461), ('5/20/2023', 1243, 'B', 'CAD', 429), ('5/20/2023', 129, 'A', 'CAD', 542), ('5/17/2023', 1206, 'A', 'USD', 319), ('5/16/2023', 1024, 'A', 'USD', 934), ('5/15/2023', 262, 'B', 'USD', 1397), ('5/14/2023', 1586, 'C', 'USD', 845), ('5/14/2023', 1465, 'A', 'CAD', 881), ('5/14/2023', 1673, 'C', 'CAD', 1305), ('5/14/2023', 1516, 'A', 'CAD', 1393), ('5/13/2023', 1470, 'C', 'USD', 1573), ('5/12/2023', 1666, 'A', 'CAD', 548), ('5/12/2023', 248, 'C', 'CAD', 1160), ('5/11/2023', 779, 'C', 'USD', 1457), ('5/9/2023', 979, 'B', 'CAD', 1263), ('5/7/2023', 1649, 'A', 'CAD', 1873), ('5/5/2023', 1295, 'A', 'USD', 140), ('5/4/2023', 976, 'C', 'CAD', 1007), ('5/3/2023', 1742, 'B', 'USD', 38), ('5/1/2023', 1214, 'A', 'CAD', 1271), ('4/29/2023', 1979, 'A', 'CAD', 1422), ('4/28/2023', 797, 'C', 'CAD', 17), ('4/28/2023', 1988, 'A', 'CAD', 1362), ('4/26/2023', 13, 'C', 'CAD', 174), ('4/25/2023', 777, 'B', 'CAD', 1859), ('4/23/2023', 771, 'A', 'CAD', 644), ('4/21/2023', 884, 'A', 'USD', 444), ('4/20/2023', 1983, 'B', 'CAD', 484), ('4/19/2023', 634, 'C', 'USD', 1636), ('4/18/2023', 1771, 'A', 'USD', 933), ('4/13/2023', 1088, 'B', 'CAD', 1601), ('4/9/2023', 1954, 'A', 'CAD', 1825), ('4/8/2023', 1315, 'B', 'CAD', 693), ('4/6/2023', 392, 'A', 'USD', 1152), ('4/6/2023', 1668, 'B', 'CAD', 1507), ('3/28/2023', 31, 'A', 'USD', 621), ('3/26/2023', 1588, 'C', 'CAD', 1551), ('3/20/2023', 620, 'C', 'CAD', 847), ('3/18/2023', 1777, 'A', 'CAD', 1968), ('3/18/2023', 1899, 'A', 'CAD', 2), ('3/18/2023', 863, 'A', 'USD', 1704), ('3/16/2023', 1789, 'A', 'CAD', 1729), ('3/12/2023', 1726, 'A', 'USD', 641), ('3/9/2023', 282, 'C', 'CAD', 1190), ('3/8/2023', 1966, 'A', 'USD', 1253), ('3/7/2023', 945, 'A', 'CAD', 174), ('3/6/2023', 422, 'C', 'USD', 931), ('3/2/2023', 452, 'B', 'USD', 1131), ('3/1/2023', 1838, 'C', 'USD', 1096), ('2/24/2023', 1425, 'C', 'CAD', 1265), ('2/23/2023', 544, 'C', 'CAD', 1193), ('2/21/2023', 904, 'B', 'USD', 1886), ('2/20/2023', 1110, 'C', 'CAD', 1637), ('2/16/2023', 717, 'B', 'USD', 97), ('2/15/2023', 1274, 'A', 'USD', 338), ('2/10/2023', 1090, 'A', 'CAD', 576), ('2/8/2023', 760, 'C', 'CAD', 1745), ('2/6/2023', 1469, 'B', 'CAD', 1349), ('2/4/2023', 928, 'B', 'USD', 1935), ('2/4/2023', 1458, 'C', 'USD', 497), ('2/3/2023', 350, 'C', 'CAD', 458), ('2/3/2023', 1901, 'B', 'USD', 1014), ('2/1/2023', 395, 'B', 'CAD', 4), ('1/24/2023', 957, 'A', 'CAD', 468), ('1/24/2023', 1690, 'C', 'USD', 1815), ('1/23/2023', 1820, 'C', 'CAD', 639), ('1/22/2023', 959, 'A', 'CAD', 821), ('1/21/2023', 1614, 'A', 'USD', 417), ('1/20/2023', 218, 'B', 'USD', 109), ('1/19/2023', 1923, 'A', 'USD', 379), ('1/16/2023', 760, 'C', 'CAD', 266), ('1/15/2023', 850, 'C', 'USD', 742), ('1/13/2023', 1868, 'C', 'USD', 847), ('1/13/2023', 1150, 'A', 'USD', 793), ('1/10/2023', 934, 'B', 'USD', 1519), ('1/6/2023', 1786, 'C', 'USD', 1105), ('12/31/2022', 1727, 'C', 'CAD', 1745), ('12/27/2022', 1469, 'C', 'USD', 387), ('12/26/2022', 1294, 'C', 'CAD', 1237), ('12/25/2022', 1943, 'A', 'USD', 954), ('12/25/2022', 428, 'A', 'CAD', 205), ('12/24/2022', 1676, 'A', 'CAD', 639), ('12/23/2022', 310, 'C', 'USD', 1719), ('12/21/2022', 1475, 'B', 'USD', 1285), ('12/19/2022', 861, 'A', 'USD', 894), ('12/19/2022', 1525, 'B', 'USD', 447), ('12/18/2022', 1099, 'A', 'CAD', 53), ('12/17/2022', 1339, 'C', 'USD', 961), ('12/17/2022', 1563, 'A', 'CAD', 1264), ('12/17/2022', 841, 'B', 'CAD', 1811), ('12/14/2022', 155, 'A', 'CAD', 733), ('12/13/2022', 1668, 'C', 'USD', 1230), ('12/13/2022', 1897, 'C', 'CAD', 191), ('12/10/2022', 1125, 'A', 'USD', 1885), ('12/10/2022', 629, 'C', 'USD', 1825), ('12/5/2022', 1012, 'A', 'USD', 1005), ('12/5/2022', 40, 'C', 'CAD', 1216), ('12/3/2022', 1613, 'A', 'USD', 1511), ('11/30/2022', 1111, 'C', 'CAD', 390), ('11/29/2022', 90, 'A', 'CAD', 933), ('11/29/2022', 1697, 'B', 'USD', 1357), ('11/27/2022', 1747, 'A', 'CAD', 827), ('11/23/2022', 70, 'C', 'CAD', 600), ('11/22/2022', 1210, 'C', 'USD', 308), ('11/21/2022', 1432, 'C', 'USD', 884), ('11/20/2022', 1585, 'B', 'CAD', 618), ('11/19/2022', 1379, 'A', 'USD', 1732), ('11/19/2022', 648, 'A', 'USD', 1502), ('11/18/2022', 1608, 'B', 'CAD', 1065), ('11/17/2022', 794, 'C', 'USD', 1702), ('11/17/2022', 1683, 'B', 'USD', 1054), ('11/16/2022', 1884, 'B', 'USD', 1713), ('11/16/2022', 1960, 'C', 'USD', 1425), ('11/14/2022', 1578, 'B', 'CAD', 1827), ('11/13/2022', 1742, 'B', 'CAD', 529), ('11/11/2022', 870, 'C', 'CAD', 1579), ('11/11/2022', 91, 'B', 'USD', 1822), ('11/10/2022', 1120, 'B', 'CAD', 319), ('11/10/2022', 1376, 'A', 'CAD', 193), ('11/9/2022', 227, 'B', 'CAD', 471), ('11/8/2022', 1323, 'B', 'CAD', 1297), ('11/6/2022', 950, 'C', 'CAD', 1021), ('11/4/2022', 1113, 'C', 'USD', 1102), ('10/31/2022', 1679, 'A', 'USD', 1128), ('10/30/2022', 1722, 'C', 'CAD', 1504), ('10/30/2022', 32, 'B', 'CAD', 1955), ('10/27/2022', 1247, 'A', 'CAD', 811), ('10/24/2022', 879, 'A', 'CAD', 1723), ('10/24/2022', 401, 'A', 'USD', 1388), ('10/24/2022', 1280, 'B', 'CAD', 1561), ('10/22/2022', 646, 'B', 'USD', 486), ('10/21/2022', 302, 'C', 'CAD', 1384), ('10/19/2022', 692, 'A', 'CAD', 1663), ('10/17/2022', 1728, 'C', 'USD', 396), ('10/17/2022', 1367, 'C', 'USD', 976), ('10/16/2022', 1877, 'A', 'CAD', 1761), ('10/11/2022', 213, 'A', 'CAD', 677), ('10/4/2022', 660, 'B', 'CAD', 1698), ('10/2/2022', 881, 'A', 'CAD', 1417), ('10/1/2022', 1651, 'A', 'CAD', 310), ('9/29/2022', 1444, 'B', 'CAD', 1264), ('9/29/2022', 1596, 'A', 'USD', 396), ('9/28/2022', 1562, 'C', 'USD', 280), ('9/26/2022', 1918, 'A', 'CAD', 625), ('9/25/2022', 1013, 'C', 'USD', 1313), ('9/24/2022', 1256, 'B', 'CAD', 1800), ('9/24/2022', 971, 'B', 'USD', 1170), ('9/23/2022', 1984, 'C', 'CAD', 1367), ('9/19/2022', 1574, 'B', 'USD', 956), ('9/18/2022', 1346, 'B', 'CAD', 472), ('9/17/2022', 442, 'B', 'CAD', 133), ('9/11/2022', 1002, 'B', 'CAD', 127), ('9/9/2022', 904, 'A', 'USD', 497), ('8/31/2022', 1354, 'B', 'USD', 590), ('8/28/2022', 1461, 'A', 'CAD', 1745), ('8/26/2022', 1176, 'B', 'CAD', 1916), ('8/24/2022', 629, 'C', 'CAD', 1534), ('8/23/2022', 391, 'C', 'USD', 1502), ('8/21/2022', 1447, 'B', 'USD', 1845), ('8/19/2022', 1030, 'C', 'USD', 1846), ('8/18/2022', 1860, 'C', 'CAD', 1051), ('8/18/2022', 1578, 'B', 'CAD', 86), ('8/18/2022', 657, 'B', 'CAD', 1408), ('8/16/2022', 412, 'A', 'USD', 89), ('8/16/2022', 947, 'C', 'CAD', 711), ('8/15/2022', 1453, 'C', 'USD', 1061), ('8/14/2022', 157, 'B', 'USD', 757), ('8/13/2022', 1429, 'B', 'USD', 187), ('8/13/2022', 1532, 'A', 'CAD', 1050), ('8/12/2022', 1478, 'B', 'USD', 1441), ('8/2/2022', 1071, 'B', 'USD', 102), ('7/31/2022', 629, 'B', 'USD', 1419), ('7/28/2022', 1150, 'A', 'USD', 830), ('7/28/2022', 805, 'B', 'USD', 1944), ('7/27/2022', 1630, 'B', 'CAD', 1182), ('7/21/2022', 1363, 'A', 'CAD', 57), ('7/19/2022', 1718, 'C', 'CAD', 1409), ('7/18/2022', 1183, 'A', 'CAD', 387), ('7/17/2022', 967, 'B', 'USD', 1734), ('7/15/2022', 1525, 'C', 'USD', 1089), ('7/14/2022', 1443, 'A', 'USD', 671), ('7/13/2022', 132, 'B', 'USD', 1817), ('7/10/2022', 1026, 'C', 'CAD', 1412), ('7/9/2022', 616, 'C', 'CAD', 1251), ('7/9/2022', 898, 'C', 'USD', 798), ('7/9/2022', 1314, 'A', 'CAD', 1459), ('7/8/2022', 500, 'B', 'CAD', 840), ('7/6/2022', 1450, 'A', 'CAD', 82), ('7/4/2022', 343, 'C', 'USD', 950), ('7/4/2022', 1422, 'A', 'USD', 1447), ('6/30/2022', 1268, 'C', 'CAD', 544), ('6/29/2022', 1705, 'A', 'CAD', 83), ('6/27/2022', 689, 'C', 'CAD', 1782), ('6/26/2022', 846, 'C', 'USD', 713), ('6/24/2022', 467, 'C', 'USD', 1641), ('6/22/2022', 1012, 'A', 'CAD', 79), ('6/20/2022', 968, 'C', 'CAD', 1681), ('6/20/2022', 854, 'C', 'CAD', 1454), ('6/19/2022', 12, 'B', 'USD', 1395), ('6/18/2022', 299, 'B', 'USD', 1372), ('6/15/2022', 626, 'B', 'USD', 543), ('6/15/2022', 1134, 'B', 'CAD', 1121), ('6/14/2022', 179, 'C', 'CAD', 1996), ('6/12/2022', 1702, 'A', 'USD', 411), ('6/11/2022', 1525, 'C', 'CAD', 3), ('6/11/2022', 122, 'A', 'CAD', 27), ('6/10/2022', 664, 'B', 'USD', 247), ('6/10/2022', 1514, 'B', 'CAD', 322), ('6/5/2022', 142, 'C', 'CAD', 1107), ('6/4/2022', 771, 'B', 'CAD', 1349), ('6/3/2022', 1447, 'B', 'CAD', 1263), ('5/29/2022', 1373, 'B', 'CAD', 895), ('5/29/2022', 1127, 'C', 'USD', 1626), ('5/28/2022', 137, 'B', 'USD', 555), ('5/24/2022', 722, 'C', 'CAD', 696), ('5/22/2022', 152, 'B', 'USD', 387), ('5/21/2022', 1128, 'C', 'USD', 1412), ('5/21/2022', 496, 'A', 'USD', 1101), ('5/19/2022', 207, 'A', 'CAD', 1570), ('5/18/2022', 885, 'A', 'USD', 862), ('5/16/2022', 572, 'B', 'CAD', 1514), ('5/12/2022', 561, 'A', 'CAD', 614), ('5/11/2022', 1183, 'B', 'CAD', 1349), ('5/10/2022', 1455, 'A', 'CAD', 1675), ('5/10/2022', 967, 'A', 'CAD', 1138), ('5/9/2022', 1833, 'B', 'USD', 733), ('5/7/2022', 1788, 'B', 'CAD', 512), ('5/7/2022', 737, 'A', 'CAD', 1210), ('5/5/2022', 216, 'B', 'CAD', 1945), ('5/2/2022', 1101, 'A', 'USD', 258), ('5/2/2022', 1290, 'C', 'USD', 1643), ('5/2/2022', 1449, 'A', 'CAD', 977), ('5/2/2022', 404, 'C', 'CAD', 1665), ('5/1/2022', 1667, 'C', 'USD', 1336), ('4/29/2022', 315, 'A', 'USD', 1766), ('4/29/2022', 1012, 'C', 'USD', 800), ('4/27/2022', 1576, 'C', 'USD', 586), ('4/25/2022', 1035, 'C', 'USD', 55), ('4/24/2022', 1358, 'B', 'USD', 523), ('4/19/2022', 441, 'A', 'CAD', 978), ('4/19/2022', 1158, 'A', 'CAD', 1037), ('4/18/2022', 1440, 'A', 'CAD', 1963), ('4/15/2022', 1280, 'A', 'USD', 658), ('4/14/2022', 444, 'B', 'USD', 1002), ('4/11/2022', 1790, 'A', 'CAD', 1704), ('4/10/2022', 1889, 'C', 'CAD', 1825), ('4/10/2022', 958, 'C', 'USD', 1255), ('4/9/2022', 1742, 'A', 'CAD', 729), ('4/8/2022', 648, 'A', 'USD', 1329), ('4/6/2022', 178, 'B', 'CAD', 1226), ('4/6/2022', 773, 'B', 'CAD', 160), ('4/6/2022', 940, 'C', 'USD', 730), ('4/5/2022', 572, 'C', 'CAD', 150), ('4/4/2022', 728, 'B', 'USD', 1503), ('4/4/2022', 195, 'B', 'CAD', 126), ('4/3/2022', 191, 'C', 'CAD', 1947), ('4/3/2022', 1708, 'B', 'USD', 290), ('4/2/2022', 1030, 'B', 'USD', 932), ('3/29/2022', 1377, 'C', 'USD', 1350), ('3/25/2022', 374, 'C', 'CAD', 777), ('3/21/2022', 1795, 'C', 'USD', 254), ('3/21/2022', 1991, 'C', 'USD', 100), ('3/20/2022', 356, 'A', 'CAD', 1280), ('3/18/2022', 1540, 'B', 'CAD', 210), ('3/16/2022', 1691, 'A', 'USD', 1643), ('3/14/2022', 1519, 'A', 'USD', 1963), ('3/12/2022', 1253, 'B', 'CAD', 827), ('3/11/2022', 960, 'B', 'CAD', 768), ('3/9/2022', 328, 'B', 'CAD', 264), ('3/3/2022', 339, 'C', 'CAD', 1185), ('3/2/2022', 672, 'B', 'CAD', 466), ('3/2/2022', 286, 'A', 'USD', 627), ('3/1/2022', 1830, 'A', 'CAD', 939), ('3/1/2022', 206, 'B', 'CAD', 1103), ('2/28/2022', 1402, 'A', 'USD', 90), ('2/26/2022', 1048, 'B', 'USD', 556), ('2/24/2022', 1272, 'B', 'USD', 1447), ('2/24/2022', 1431, 'C', 'CAD', 1843), ('2/24/2022', 468, 'A', 'CAD', 934), ('2/22/2022', 1998, 'C', 'USD', 44), ('2/22/2022', 247, 'B', 'USD', 327), ('2/18/2022', 956, 'B', 'USD', 1992), ('2/18/2022', 627, 'A', 'USD', 406), ('2/13/2022', 642, 'A', 'CAD', 384), ('2/13/2022', 1214, 'C', 'CAD', 1506), ('2/11/2022', 97, 'A', 'CAD', 556), ('2/11/2022', 434, 'A', 'CAD', 1259), ('2/7/2022', 738, 'A', 'USD', 354), ('2/7/2022', 492, 'B', 'USD', 140), ('2/6/2022', 498, 'A', 'USD', 1914), ('2/5/2022', 196, 'A', 'USD', 1144), ('2/5/2022', 1474, 'B', 'USD', 618), ('2/5/2022', 1639, 'A', 'CAD', 429), ('2/2/2022', 1847, 'A', 'USD', 1947), ('1/27/2022', 1304, 'C', 'CAD', 1331), ('1/27/2022', 613, 'C', 'CAD', 2000), ('1/26/2022', 1989, 'B', 'USD', 1675), ('1/26/2022', 1489, 'C', 'CAD', 611), ('1/26/2022', 715, 'C', 'CAD', 116), ('1/26/2022', 943, 'A', 'CAD', 397), ('1/23/2022', 1137, 'B', 'USD', 1415), ('1/23/2022', 153, 'B', 'CAD', 835), ('1/22/2022', 679, 'C', 'USD', 1286), ('1/21/2022', 1065, 'A', 'CAD', 1216), ('1/21/2022', 1282, 'A', 'CAD', 38), ('1/20/2022', 1759, 'B', 'USD', 1815), ('1/20/2022', 216, 'C', 'USD', 905), ('1/19/2022', 1756, 'A', 'USD', 995), ('1/18/2022', 1528, 'A', 'USD', 2000), ('1/17/2022', 459, 'C', 'CAD', 545), ('1/14/2022', 1261, 'A', 'CAD', 618), ('1/13/2022', 1931, 'B', 'USD', 1092), ('1/11/2022', 1448, 'C', 'CAD', 464), ('1/10/2022', 943, 'C', 'CAD', 700), ('1/9/2022', 977, 'B', 'CAD', 711), ('1/8/2022', 1567, 'B', 'USD', 228), ('1/7/2022', 1545, 'A', 'CAD', 1019), ('1/6/2022', 361, 'C', 'USD', 922), ('1/6/2022', 250, 'A', 'CAD', 1245), ('1/5/2022', 877, 'A', 'CAD', 1032), ('1/5/2022', 1584, 'C', 'CAD', 1959), ('1/5/2022', 198, 'C', 'CAD', 939), ('1/4/2022', 1069, 'B', 'USD', 699), ('9/17/2021', 1463, 'C', 'CAD', 733);
```

here

```
select sum(amount)
from test
where product = 'A'
    and day >= '2022-11-01'
```

returns `66776`, as that would be the right sum for trailing twelve months for october 2023.

The same result here:

```
with monthly as
(
select
    id,
    product,
    cur,
    date_trunc('month', day) :: date as month,
    sum(amount) as monthly_total
from test
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
)

select
    sum(monthly_total)
from monthly
where product = 'A'
    and month <= '2023-10-01'
    and month > '2022-10-01';
```

But the following give the wrong answer

```
select sum(ttm_total) s
from (
    select
        id,
        product,
        cur,
        month,
        sum(monthly_total) over (partition by id, product, cur
                                order by month
                                rows between 12 preceding and current row)
                                as ttm_total
    from monthly) x
where product = 'A'
    and month = '2023-10-01'
```

returns `558`

This also returns `558`:

```
with monthly as
(
select
    id,
    product,
    cur,
    date_trunc('month', day) :: date as month,
    sum(amount) as monthly_total
from test
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
),

test as
(
    SELECT
        b1.id,
        b1.product,
        b1.cur,
        b1.month,
        (
            SELECT SUM(monthly_total) AS ttm_total
            FROM monthly AS b2
            WHERE date_diff('month', b2.month, b1.month) <= 12
                AND b1.id = b2.id
                AND b1.product = b2.product
                AND b1.cur = b2.cur
        ) AS ttm_total
    FROM monthly AS b1
)
select
    sum(ttm_total) s -- 558
from test
where product = 'A'
    and month = '2023-10-01';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nm, figured it out ... The problem was that there were missing months for each set of (id, product, cur). This solved it:

```
with monthly as
(
select
    id,
    product,
    cur,
    date_trunc('month', day) :: date as month,
    sum(amount) as monthly_total
from test
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
),

dates as
(
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            date_add(
                'day', row_number() OVER () - 1, '2019-01-01'
            )::date AS full_date,
            date_part('day', full_date) AS month_day_number
        FROM some_table_with_enough_rows_to_account_for_all_dates
    ) AS d
WHERE full_date <= '2024-01-01'
ORDER BY full_date DESC
),

all_months as
(
select
    d.month,
    m.id,
    m.product,
    m.cur,
    (select monthly_total
     from monthly m2
     where m2.id = m.id
       and m2.product = m.product
       and m2.cur = m.cur
       and m2.month = d.month) as monthly_total
from
(
    select
        distinct date_trunc('month', full_date) :: date as month
    from dates
    where month between '2021-01-01' and getdate()
) d
cross join
(
    select
         id,
         product,
         cur
    from monthly
    group by 1, 2, 3
) as m
group by id, product, cur, month
order by id, product, cur, month
)


select sum(ttm_total) s
from (
    select
        id,
        product,
        cur,
        month,
        sum(monthly_total) over (partition by id, product, cur
                                order by month
                                rows between 11 preceding and current row) as ttm_total
from all_months) x
where product = 'A'
    and month = '2023-10-01'
```

(i copy pasted the `dates` table from my db, but it could be simplified for this particular scenario to only contain months, not individual days)

The snippet with `date_diff('month', b2.month, b1.month) <= 12` also works, just need to change `<=12` to `<12`